# Is there a way to translate API Information (alexa developer console, -pip install dont work)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I currently have an API for my weather intent, but I need to translate the main Information like Snow, sun, rain and so on. Has anyone an Idea how I can translate them before it goes to the speak_output ?

```
class wetterHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Get Weather Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("wetter")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        api_url= "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=München&appid=b9ad6b1c8e80f623ff23a53cdd8832a9&units=metric"
        json_data = requests.get(api_url).json()
        weather_json = json_data['weather'][0]['main']
        temp_json = round(json_data['main']['temp'] )
        city = "München"
        speak_output = "The weather is {} and temperature is {} °C in {}. " .format(weather_json, temp_json, city)
        reprompt = "Want to try again? Or you can say cancel to quit."
        handler_input.response_builder
        
        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(reprompt)
                .response
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply [specify the language](https://openweathermap.org/current#multi) in your request URL like so:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=524901&appid={API key}&lang={lang}
```

So to get the weather in German you would make a request to:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=München&appid=b9ad6b1c8e80f623ff23a53cdd8832a9&units=metric&lang=de
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Solved :
Got all the possible returns of the API and put just a simple if before the code print the speakout:

```
def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        api_url= "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=München&appid=b9ad6b1c8e80f623ff23a53cdd8832a9&units=metric"
        json_data = requests.get(api_url).json()
        weather_json = json_data['weather'][0]['main']
        if weather_json == "Snow":
            weather_json = "am Schneien"
        if weather_json == "Rain":
            weather_json = "Regnerisch"
        if weather_json == "Clouds":
            weather_json = "Bewölkt"
        if weather_json == "Sun":
            weather_json = "Sonnig"
        if weather_json == "Wind":
            weather_json = "Windig"
        temp_json = round(json_data['main']['temp'] )
        city = "München"
        speak_output = "Aktuell ist es {} und die Temperatur beträgt {} °C in {}. Wie sollen wir fortfahren? " .format(weather_json, temp_json, city)
        reprompt = "Möchtest du nochmal das Wetter abfragen?"
        handler_input.response_builder
        
        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(reprompt)
                .response
        )
```

Comment: You've overcomplicated this, see my answer